# SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist in node-oracledb

Tags: sql, oracle, node-oracledb

I'm using the node-oracledb driver to connect a local database to my web app. When I try selecting data from the database in my node program, I get Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist, but running the select query locally from sqldeveloper works fine.

When I run

```
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW')
AND object_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

in sqldeveloper to make sure the table exist, I get the schema name under owner, table name under object_name, and table under object_type; however, when I run the same query from my node program, an empty set is returned (no values for owner, table name, or object type). I'm connected to a second oracle db already in my node application which is working fine, so I don't think it has to do with the oracle db driver. I've checked my configuration as well, and the path and username/password are the same as those I used to establish the connection in sqldeveloper.

In the node program, my query contains schema and table info.

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
```

This query produces the output Error:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist, but works fine in sql developer. Any ideas as to what could be going on?

Comment: Are you connecting with the same user in Node and SQL Developer?

Comment: Yes -- I ran "select USER,SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') from dual" in both SQL dev and my Node program and got the same output. Same user in both cases.

Comment: Maybe grants are given to a role, and not to the user?

Comment: If your Node program is connecting to two databases, are you sure you're running these queries against the right one? (There are a few ways to check; querying `global_name` view is one). Are you connected as the owner in both sessions?

Comment: @AlexPoole -- it looks like I was running the query against the first database (db1). Any insight as to why? This is my process:
I Initialize a db module with db1 by creating a pool using the specific config for that db. 
Then do the same for db2 (new pool). The configs differ in the connectstring (same user/pw).
Then make 2 api calls to the 2 db's, first to db1. In this call, I establish a single connection in the pool, execute a query, and close the connection. Repeat for db2. As the configs are different, and I am using two different pools, why would I be querying db1?

Comment: @AlexPoole just for clarification--the first db (db1) queries are working fine. The original question was concerning the second db. Both queries were actually running against db1, as you pointed out.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Node so would be guessing at best. I'd suggest you ask a new question specifically about that issue and include a [mre]. (You could edit this one but it's probably simpler now to start a new one, and then delete this...)

Comment: @AlexPoole -- I got it. While I was creating two separate pools, I was calling getConnection on the same db by accident. Thanks!